# Using R and radian in vscode when it remotely connect to ubuntu in VMware

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

my environment:
windows11
VMware 17 pro
ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64

I install the anaconda3 on the ubuntu,then I create a env called `r431` with `R 4.3.1` and `radian`, BTW, I didn't change the `.bashrc` except conda init
I use VScode to remotely connect ubuntu. And this is my `settings.json`

```
{
    "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {
        "ubuntu2204": "linux"
    },
    "r.bracketedPaste": true,
    "r.plot.useHttpgd": true,
    "r.rpath.linux": "/home/toxin/anaconda3/envs/r431/bin/R",
    "r.rterm.linux": "/home/toxin/anaconda3/envs/r431/bin/radian",
    "r.rterm.option": [
        "--no-site-file",
        "--r-binary=/home/toxin/anaconda3/envs/r431/bin/R"
    ]
}
```

I can activate the radian, and run the code, but I **can't install packages**, this is an example `r$> install.packages("stringr")`

```
* installing *source* package ‘stringi’ ...
** package ‘stringi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
/home/toxin/anaconda3/envs/r431/lib/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not found
/home/toxin/anaconda3/envs/r431/lib/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not found
/home/toxin/anaconda3/envs/r431/lib/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not found
/home/toxin/anaconda3/envs/r431/lib/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not found
/home/toxin/anaconda3/envs/r431/lib/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not found
/home/toxin/anaconda3/envs/r431/lib/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not found
Error in system2(file.path(R.home("bin"), "R"), c("CMD", "config", x),  : 
  error in running command
* removing ‘/home/toxin/anaconda3/envs/r431/lib/R/library/stringi’
ERROR: dependency ‘stringi’ is not available for package ‘stringr’
* removing ‘/home/toxin/anaconda3/envs/r431/lib/R/library/stringr’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpqtjmB0/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("stringr") :
  installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("stringr") :
  installation of package ‘stringr’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with `vscode` or `radian`. Your error is that `make` is not found. You need to make sure that `base-r-dev` is installed on your ubuntu environment - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49844820/r-packages-not-installing-on-rstudio-server).

Comment: other errors comes... 
sh: 1: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++: not found  
./configure: 77: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc: not found

Comment: Have you tried `conda install gxx_linux-64`? See [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/770)

Comment: I tried, doesn't work

Comment: I would stick with conda packages, conda-forge includes current `stringi`, 1.7.12 . And you might save a ton of time if you switch to `mamba` for managing your conda environments (like tens of minutes when resolving  dependencies for existing envs).

Comment: I think this is a common issue because I am unable to install any packages, Perhaps it's due to environmental issues